# by which time she was bursting

Tags: meaning

*She had another bottle of Heineken to pluck up the courage to go to the loo, **by which time she was bursting**.*

I am not sure what the relative clause in the above sentence exactly means and which word modifies. Does it say that she was bursting during the time spent in the toilet or that she was bursting during her way to the loo.

P. S. Does the word "burst" in the conext mean the explosion of laugh (the phrase "burst out laughing")?

Comment: bursting in this context means that she was in danger of pissing before reaching the toilet.

Comment: Someone thought their bladder might burst if they didn't go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**By which time** could refer to

1. the time by which she had finished the bottle of Heineken
2. the time by which she had plucked up the courage to go to the loo.

Here is a definition of [bursting](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bursting)

This sentence could be rewritten as

> She had another bottle of Heineken to pluck up the courage to go to the loo, and by the time **she had sufficient courage** she was **scarcely able to avoid involuntary urination**.